# Facebook profile details

Tags: social-network

I have a webform (survey) on my site, some of the fields are personal details (age, name, DOB, etc). I want to actually force the user to login with facebook and pro grammatically obtain those few details from facebook.

Which module(s) would I be most interested in, in achieving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no module that can do this for you. You would need to make your own according to what fields you want. You would need to use the Facebook SDK and PHP (or Javascript) to query the `graph` and fill in the details you need.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/ for details on how to get the data.

Comment: I was starting to get that impression as well, as I researched deeper

Answer (score 0):

Find the drupal facebook module listing on [this link](https://groups.drupal.org/node/65268)

So far I find [fb module](https://drupal.org/project/fb) will be worth starting with.

> This set of modules turns Drupal into a platform for developing
>   Facebook Applications. This allows you to embed your content and
>   features within facebook, or allow facebook users onto your site via
>   Facebook Connect.

A quick glance for module description is [here](https://drupal.org/node/195035).